# Purpose of 'type' argument in DataContractJsonSerializer when given known types

Tags: c#, serialization

Per MSDN, the first argument of the constructor, [`DataContractJsonSerializer(Type, IEnumerable<Type>)`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb908209(v=vs.110).aspx), is defined as *The type of the instances that are serialized or deserialized*.

However, I recently encountered a bug in some product code, but then quickly realized the serialization worked as expected. A simplified version of this is:

```
var knownTypes = new[] { typeof(TypeA), typeof(TypeB) };

// Bug below. Should be 'otherType = typeof(C)'
// Always sets otherType to System.RuntimeType
var otherType = typeof(TypeC).GetType();

var serializer = new DataContractJsonSerializer(otherType, knownTypes);

using(var output = new MemoryStream())
{
    serializer.WriteObject(output, new TypeA());
    output.Position = 0;
    var copy = (TypeA) serializer.ReadObject(output);
}
```

This is because the serializer will successfully write any object with types specified in the `type` argument **or** the `knownTypes` argument.

**My questions are:**

If the serializer can properly write objects of types specified in either argument, what is the purpose of having the first argument?

Is there any special case where the first argument is treated differently, or holds a special purpose to the serializer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe the idea is that knowing what type is *expected* will help the `DataContractJsonSerializer` to print out type information in the event of polymorphic operations.

```
class Foo
{
    public string a { get; set; }
}

class Bar : Foo
{
    public string b { get; set; }
}
```

Let's say, for the remainder of my examples, that you initialize your serializer as follows:

```
var s = new DataContractJsonSerializer(typeof(Foo), new Type[] { typeof(Bar) });
s.EmitTypeInformation = EmitTypeInformation.AsNeeded;
```

After doing that, you begin to use it:

1. After doing that, you pass it an instance of `Foo` to serialize, it will serialize a single property, `a` and that will be that. `{ "a" : "valueA" }`
2. Now, you pass it an instance of `Bar`. Hold on, `typeof(Foo) != typeof(Bar)`. The serializer sees this and recognizes that the deserializing client could get confused by it, or best case, could simply jump over some data. Thus, it prints out explicit type information. `{ "__type" : "Bar", "a : "valueA", "b", "valueB" }`
3. Now let's say you pass it an instance of something totally random, say, `DateTime`. Again, it checks and sees that, woah, `typeof(DateTime) != typeof(Foo)`, so here the client could get *seriously* confused. Thus, the "__type" property is added again. This rids us, as much as we can be rid anyway, of the risk.

So in non-buggy usage, it's mostly just a matter of preserving polymorphic parameters through serialization.

Furthermore, it doesn't use `Type.IsAssignableFrom(Type)` because that's just not necessary and would cause exceptions that could unnecessary frustrate, so when your code was calling it with the type `Type` and sending it a `TypeA` to be serialized, it was checking if `Type == value.GetType()`, deciding it wasn't the expected type, and printing out that extra, unnecessary type information.

Comment: Very good point with the `EmitTypeInformation` property. I did not even think of that because our system is still in .NET 4.0, where this property is not available. I would point out that attempting to serialize a derived type `Bar` will throw an exception unless you specify it as a `knownType`.

Comment: In fact, I think the type information is the answer. In 4.0, emitting type information was "AsNeeded" by default. The first `type` argument, has a special meaning in that if the object to be serialized matches, type information will be skipped when writing.

Comment: Ah yes, I had forgotten about those. I switched to JSON.net a little while ago so I haven't been used to this stuff. That's better, right? I'm on my phone so checking documentation is difficult.